# How can you get around the 2GB buffer limit when using Dataset.groupByKey?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

When using `Dataset.groupByKey(_.key).mapGroups` or `Dataset.groupByKey(_.key).cogroup` in Spark, I've run into a problem when one of the groupings results in more than 2GB of data.

I need to normalize the data by group before I can start to reduce it, and I would like to split up the groups into smaller subgroups so they distribute better. For example, here's one way I've attempted to split the groups:

```
val groupedInputs = inputData.groupByKey(_.key).mapGroups {
    case(key, inputSeries) => inputSeries.grouped(maxGroupSize).map(group => (key, group))
}
```

But unfortunately however I try to work around it, my jobs always die with an error like this: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot grow BufferHolder by size 23816 because the size after growing exceeds size limitation 2147483632`. When using Kryo serialization I get a different `Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow` error recommending I increase spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max, but I've already increased it to the 2GB limit.

One solution that occurs to me is to add a random value to the keys before grouping them. This isn't ideal since it'll split up every group (not just the large ones), but I'm willing to sacrifice "ideal" for the sake of "working". That code would look something like this:

```
val splitInputs = inputData.map( record => (record, ThreadLocalRandom.current.nextInt(splitFactor)))
val groupedInputs = splitInputs.groupByKey{ case(record, split) => (record.key, split)).mapGroups {
    case((key, _), inputSeries) => inputSeries.grouped(maxGroupSize).map(group => (key, group.map(_._1)))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, where the dataset had a lot of skew and it was important to group the records into regularly-sized groups, I decided to process the dataset in two passes. First I used a window function to number the rows by key, and converted that to a "group index," based on a configurable "maxGroupSize":

```
// The "orderBy" doesn't seem necessary here, 
// but the row_number function requires it.
val partitionByKey = Window.partitionBy(key).orderBy(key)

val indexedData = inputData.withColumn("groupIndex", 
  (row_number.over(partitionByKey) / maxGroupSize).cast(IntegerType))
  .as[(Record, Int)]
```

Then I can group by key and index, and produce groups that are consistently sized--the keys with a lot of records get split up more, and the keys with few records may not be split up at all.

```
indexedData.groupByKey{ case (record, groupIndex) => (record.key, groupIndex) }
  .mapGroups{ case((key, _), recordGroup) =>
      // Remove the index values before returning the groups
      (key, recordGroup.map(_._1))
  }
```

Comment: Avoid groupByKey() when you are sure about the groupings results in more than 2GB of data. For Larger sets of data, prefer reduceByKey(). For more info refer:
https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Comment: @Prazy that is generally good advice--avoid groupByKey and use reduceByKey instead--but not practical in this particular case since I'm doing a "map" operation rather than a "reduce." That's why I'm going to so much trouble to split up the keys into smaller groups.

Answer (score 2):

Add a salt key and do groupBy on your key and the salt key and later

```
import scala.util.Random
    val start = 1
      val end   = 5
      val randUdf = udf({() => start + Random.nextInt((end - start) + 1)})

      val saltGroupBy=skewDF.withColumn("salt_key", randUdf())
        .groupBy(col("name"), col("salt_key"))
```

So your all the skew data doesn't go into one executor and cause the 2GB Limit.

But you have to develop a logic to aggregate the above result and finally remove the salt key at the end.

When you use groupBy all the records with the same key will reach one executor and bottle neck occur. 
The above is one of the method to mitigate it.

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what I am doing except you are using the Dataframe API. If I may suggest something: instead of using a UDF here, you could use the built-in `rand` function like this: `skewDF.withColumn("salt_key", (rand * 5).cast(IntegerType))`
That should perform better than the UDF version.